# Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000 ms exceeded while using Nbconvert

Tags: python, nbconvert

I am using the following command : **jupyter nbconvert  --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download PNM.ipynb**, to convert Jupiter notebook to a pdf file.

However, there is a timeout error. According to the documentation: "The timeout option can also be set to None or -1 to remove any restriction on execution time.". But, I am unaware as to how to use it.

Comment: try `jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 PNM.ipynb`

Comment: Hey Nikunj, I tried it already. The same error persists: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000 ms exceeded.

Comment: I think this link helps you [discussion](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/1489)